# AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'experimental' problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am trying to set up a object detection api in Google Colab.
I am trying to follow this tutorial and downloaded the models from github

[Object Detection Tuturial](https://medium.com/swlh/tensorflow-2-object-detection-api-with-google-colab-b2af171e81cc)

[Github Model Garden](https://github.com/tensorflow/models)

I downladed the recent centernet_resnet50_v1_fpn_512x512_coco17_tpu-8 from [Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md)

When I tried to start the training (step 15 from the tutorial)I got a error like this

`File "model_main_tf2.py", line 31, in <module> from object_detection import model_lib_v2 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.7.egg/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 31, in <module> from object_detection import model_lib File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.7.egg/object_detection/model_lib.py", line 35, in <module> from object_detection.builders import optimizer_builder File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.7.egg/object_detection/builders/optimizer_builder.py", line 25, in <module> from official.modeling.optimization import ema_optimizer File "/content/gdrive/My Drive/TensorFlow/models/official/modeling/optimization/__init__.py", line 23, in <module> from official.modeling.optimization.optimizer_factory import OptimizerFactory File "/content/gdrive/My Drive/TensorFlow/models/official/modeling/optimization/optimizer_factory.py", line 36, in <module> 'adamw_experimental': tf.keras.optimizers.experimental.AdamW, AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'experimental'`

When I read AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'experimental, I fed it to google found two possible solution of using tf-nightly and solution from this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/10525) but still failed.

What could cause the error? If the tutorial is outdated, what adjustment shd I make to make it work?

Thank you so so much.

Comment: Hi @Leo Wong, Colab uses Tensorflow 2.8,  `tf.keras.optimizers.experimental.AdamW` is available in Tensorflow 2.9. Please upgrade Tensorflow 2.8 to Tensorflow 2.9 and let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.

Comment: I fixed it by downgraded the opencv-python-headless to 4.1.2.30